# I want an ajax response with string and image with spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, image, spring-mvc, blob

I want to offer an interface, response `ResponseMessage` with `responseCode(String)` and `data(byte[] or BufferedImage)` which I would request with `xhr(type:Blob)` and get the response.

If its `responseCode` is success, I would show the image saved in data.

I have tried response byte[] and BufferedImage Data, using FileReader and img src to show. But it's of no use and its Content-Type is always `"application/json"`. If I set the response type to `"image/jpeg"`, there will be no Blob. Otherwise I can get the right Blob but I can't translate the  Blob to image. What should I do?

This is my ResponseMessage Class:

```
public class ResponseMessage<T> {
    public String responseCode;
    public T data;

    public String getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public void setResponseCode(String responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This is response BufferedImage data:

```
if(maxRect.area()>0) {
            Mat roi_img = new Mat(image, maxRect);
            Mat tmp_img = new Mat();
            roi_img.copyTo(tmp_img);
            Imgproc.resize(tmp_img,tmp_img,new Size(50,50));
            responseMessage.setResponseCode("00");
            responseMessage.setData(Mat2BufferedImage(tmp_img));
            return responseMessage;
        }
static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat matrix)throws Exception {
        MatOfByte mob=new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", matrix, mob);
        byte ba[]=mob.toArray();

        BufferedImage bi=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba));
        return bi;
    }
```

This is response byte[] data:

```
if(maxRect.area()>0) {
            Mat roi_img = new Mat(image, maxRect);
            Mat tmp_img = new Mat();
            roi_img.copyTo(tmp_img);
            Imgproc.resize(tmp_img,tmp_img,new Size(50,50));
            responseMessage.setResponseCode("00");
            byte[] return_buff = new byte[(int) (tmp_img.total() *
                    tmp_img.channels())];
            tmp_img.get(0, 0, return_buff);
            responseMessage.setData(return_buff);
            return responseMessage;
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks,I am not a native English Speaker,I have been search questions for a long time and it's my first time ask question.It's my bad.It's 11pm in my country so I am in a hurry.I am sorry.